Fantasy book series with each book being about a different colored dragon?
Hello I'm looking for a book series that had a different colored dragon on the cover of each book. The background was tan and the dragon was in the center. The ones I remember were red, green, silver, copper, and bronze but I believe there were others.
I read the one with the red dragon and it was about a dwarf who wanted to kill the red dragon either for money or revenge. He spent a long time working on his axe to make it strong enough to take down the dragon. There was some kind of fight in a desert as well.
I read these books about 10ish years ago.

Is this the Dragon Codices series by R.D. Henham...?

Book 1: Red Dragon Codex (2008)
Book 2: Bronze Dragon Codex (2008)
Book 3: Black Dragon Codex (2008)
Book 4: Brass Dragon Codex (2009)
Book 5: Green Dragon Codex (2009)
Book 6: Silver Dragon Codex (2009)
Book 7: Gold Dragon Codex (2010)

The covers of the books match your description, with the cover of the first book featuring a red dragon on a tan background.

The Goodreads blurb for the first book:

The Dragon Codices chronicle adventures with each of ten dragons of Krynn. From the fiery, evil red dragon to the playful copper, each dragon's tale is unique. Sindri Suncatcher, narrator of A Practical Guide to Dragons , shared these tales from his travels with library scribe R.D. Henham.
Mudd lives a peaceful life in his small town, tinkering with the mill and any mechanical devices that he can find. But his peaceful life soon changes when, out of nowhere, a red dragon attacks, burning the town and kidnapping Shemnara, the village seer. Only one clue is left behind--a cryptic note telling Mudd, "Seek the silver dragon."

The first book is available to borrow at the Internet Archive.

Wouldn't it be The Inheritance Cycle? Each covers has a different dragon head color.
Dunno if i'm allowed to copy paste links but i'll try : https://www.amazon.fr/Inheritance-4-Book-Eragon-Eldest-Brisingr/dp/030793067X

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Also, given that another answer has been accepted you'll need to be extremely convincing as to why you think this is what the OP was looking for

@Vaggarath I’ve read some of the books in this series, and it definitely doesn’t fit the answer. The MC in the series you gave is a human, not a dwarf bent on revenge via axe as mentioned by the OP. Also, there is no desert in the Inheritance Cycle, at least not in the first few books.
